# Как использовать XML для создания окон Windows в паре с С++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gui

Работаю над приложением используя WINAPI/C++. Так как проект становится все сложнее, начинаю путаться в коде,  который отвечает за графический интерфейс. Есть ли у VISUAL STUDIO (и вообще существуют ли)  способы создавать интерфейс с помощью каких нибудь XML в паре с С++, как на подобе в Android Studio Java/XML?

Comment: Почему именно XML? Этот формат многие считают неудобным из-за многословности. У Qt вроде есть декларативный синтаксис для GUI, но не в виде XML. См. также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875489/

Comment: wxWidgets умеет использовать описания на XML. Для работы с ней (библиотекой GUI) есть плагин для CodeBlocks - wxSmith - он использует XML; есть отдельный (от всяческих IDE) дизайнер wxFormBuilder (умеет делать код для разных языков: c++,python, php, lua). Также, есть возможность в проект подключать файл ресурсов wx XRC (это тоже XML).