# Как открыть дизайнер формы в проекте Windows Application C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Всем привет.
В общем, создал проект Windows Application С++.
При запуске без ошибок создаётся красивая форма. Но проблема - нет дизайнера, как мне создавать кнопки, лейблы и т.д?
Скрин:

[image]

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то дизайнер доступен только для проектов c++/cli. В проекте Windows Application - все элементы создаются ручками кодом.

Comment: @Александр :(, эх... Просто WinForms там морочится долго, Visual C++ WinForms плохо поддерживает

Comment: Использовать внешнюю утилиту. Что-то вроде [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) или [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а ей то как пользоваться? У меня установлен Resource Hacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. В проектах неуправляемых приложений Windows можно разве что использовать редактор ресурсов диалоговых окон для визуального редактирования интерфейса:

1. В обозревателе решений **Файлы ресурсов** - два раза нажать по .rc файлу (если нет, создать)
2. В левой панели (**Окно ресурсов**) правой кнопкой - Добавить ресурс - Dialog
3. Откроется интерфейс редактора ресурсов диалоговых окон.

Подробнее о том, как это работает, см. здесь:  [C++ WinApi отделить UI View от кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/875489/240512)

Но для удобной работы с GUI в режиме конструктора (как в .NET Windows Forms) в неуправляемых приложениях нужно что-то типа [MFC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?view=vs-2019).

Comment: А как сделать MFC программу в Visual Studio? Пишу поиск в сети и в С++ проектах - MFC не найдено.

Comment: @SharpPythoneist Выбрав компонент "MFC and ATL support" в Visual Studio Installer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10857/cant-find-the-template-for-mfc-programming-in-file.html